# Building FFMPEGINTEROP with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I'm working on a project that requires a video player. I've been using the standard UWP MediaPlayerElement but it refuses to read many types of videos, including ASF and FLV and some older MPG.

I've read that ffmpeginterop is more compatible with a variety of codecs. However building it is a finicky and all the instructions are designed for VS2015 and command prompt for ARM processor, which does not exist for VS2017. I can't find an updated version of the instructions (Left a message on their GIT site as well... no answers).

So my question is two-fold:

1. Is there any way to download the missing/updated codecs to include them in my project that uses the standard UWP approach?
2. Is there an updated way/tutorial/instructions of building ffmpeginterop with VS2017?
3. Is ffmpeginterop too old and I should not build using it going forward?

Thanks!

Comment: I need ffmerp for join audio to video  :) please find any solution ::)

Comment: It seems, from the Git repository, that someone has a pulled request to support VS2017. But no reviews yet!

So my question is still: any ways to download codecs with the existing UWP MediaPlayerElement?

Comment: nuget has FFMPEGINTEROP u try it ?

Comment: Oh yeah Omansak... why isn't it written anywhere! All the docs I could find refered to building it yourself.... Yes, it works! Thanks!